# 3D Touch Peek turns the screen white

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, uistoryboardsegue, 3dtouch

I am trying to add a 3D Touch *Preview & Commit Segue* to my app, but for some reason whenever I try to peek in the iOS Simulator the area behind the view controller being peeked turns completely white, whereas it is meant to be blurred. This happened even when I tried implementing 3D Touch programatically in another app.

In the app where I did it using storyboards, I selected the following options for the segue:

[image: Segue Options]

And I tried to do it programatically in another app by following these steps (I have the same bug in that app too):

1. Call `registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: view)` in `viewDidLoad`
2. Implement `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate` as follows:

   1. In `previewingContext(_:viewControllerForLocation:)`, fetch the correct indexPath, set the context's source rect to it, instantiate the detail navigation controller from the storyboard, and return it.
   2. In `previewingContext(_:commit:)`, push `(viewControllerToCommit as? UINavigationController)?.rootViewController` onto the navigation stack.

I'm not entirely sure whether this bug is specific to the iOS Simulator, since I don't have a 3D Touch enabled iOS device, but are there any additional steps required to correctly implement peeking and popping?

Here is an example of the bug that I'm encountering:

[image: 3D Touch Peek Bug]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @user4992124 I tested it on a device, and it works there. [Here's a gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa5rM.gif) of it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to test the apps on a 3D Touch capable iOS device, and I can confirm that Peek and Pop works perfectly on the device with both apps. I have hence come to the conclusion that this is a simulator-specific bug.

[image: Peek and Pop on iPhone]

Comment: Yep, I came to the same solution the morning after a night of trying to fix this.